# Why android studio is telling me that enum.valueOf is always true?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, enums, null

I have a little strange question. This is my enum:

```
enum ErrorInByte{
    ERROR_BIT0(3),
    ERROR_BIT2(4),
    ERROR_BIT3(5),
    ERROR_BIT4(7),
    ERROR_BIT5(13),
    ERROR_BIT7(15),

    private int value;
    ErrorInByte(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static ErrorInByte valueOf(int value){
        return intToErrorInByte.get(value);
    }

    private static final Map<Integer, ErrorInByte> intToErrorInByte= new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (ErrorInByte type : ErrorInByte.values()) {
            intToErrorInByte.put(type.value, type);
        }
    }
}
```

In my class I have an if:

```
int n;
//Code that changes n to a value
if(n > 0 && ErrorInByte.valueOf(n) != null){
//do stuff...
}
```

Why android studio tells me that ErrorInByte.valueOf(n) is always true? I tested it and for `ErrorInByte.valueOf(326)`  it equals null.

Warning message :

```
This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.


Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or @NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check nullability contracts, e.g. report possible NullPointerException errors.

More complex contracts can be defined using @Contract annotation, for example:

@Contract("_, null -> null") — method returns null if its second argument is null 
@Contract("_, null -> null; _, !null -> !null") — method returns null if its second argument is null and not-null otherwise 
@Contract("true -> fail") — a typical assertFalse method which throws an exception if true is passed to it 

The inspection can be configured to use custom @Nullable
    @NotNull annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used)
```

Is there any way to remove the warning? I hate warnings...

Comment: Because you've not got an element in the map with value 326.

Comment: Make sure value is present or not

Comment: Your question and your explanation makes no sense. First you say it's always null then you say it's always true...

Comment: Could you post your warning message?

Comment: @Georgi This might help you [Set android studio warning levels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642964/set-android-studio-warning-levels)

Comment: @Raghavendra That is one way to fix it but I want to try fix the warning instead of disabling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happen is that `Enums` already have a non override able `valueOf` method. This means that you are in fact calling your own defined `valueOf`, but the IDE assumes that it's the static `valueOf`. So in order to fix your issue you have to rename your method to something like

```
 public static ErrorInByte lookUpByCode(int value){
        return intToErrorInByte.get(value);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't thought of that. Changed the name and it's ok now... Thanks